# Issue with file reading and vector entries

Tags: c++, vector, readfile

The purpose of this program is to read a text file and store its contents in 3 separate vectors.

The text file, called "InsultsSource.txt", contains 50 rows of tab-delimited columns of adjectives that looks like this:

```
happy    sad    angry
tired    mad    hungry
```

Below is the code I'm using to achieve this. For some reason, the everything works until the 16th line at which point empty spaces are returned. I've checked the text file to see if the format changes around there but it looks fine. I'm just wondering if there's any error in my logic/code that is causing this problem.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream fileIn("InsultsSource.txt");
    vector<string> col1;
    vector<string> col2;
    vector<string> col3;
    string word;

    if (fileIn.fail()) {
        cerr << "Unable to open file" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            getline(fileIn, word, '\t');
            col1.push_back(word);
        }
        else if (i % 3 == 1) {
            getline(fileIn, word, '\t');
            col2.push_back(word);
        }
        else {
            getline(fileIn, word);
            col3.push_back(word);
        }
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < 50; j++) {
        cout << j+1 << " " << col1[j] << endl;
        //cout << "Thou " << col1[j] << " " << col2[j] << " " << col3[j] << "!" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your assuming 50 entries in the file.  A better algorithm is to read *while* there is data in the file.

Comment: Doesn't the second `for` loop (containing `j` and `cout`) cause a crash, as you are iterating past the array boundary?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews You are right. I just thought since I'm just trying to get this to work, and I know there are 50 lines, it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @UnholySheep Each column should have 50 entries so I'm not sure why you think it'd crash.

Comment: Do you see how much time you saved by that shortcut?

Comment: @Beta Sass?.. I guess it's deserved.

Comment: @AndréFoote your "reading loop" only adds elements to `col1` when `i%3 == 0` ergo only in 1/3 of the iteration. So `col1` only contains 16 elements after the first `for` loop

Comment: Get rid of your state machine. It is overcomplicated and redundant. You need three action per iteration (read the first word, read the second word, read the third word). Just do them one by one without checking whether some ill-conceived counter is a multiple of three or something.

Comment: @UnholySheep Yeah, I just realized. Ofc I'm wrong, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading in 50 words *total,* then trying to print 50 words *from each column.*

Comment: Yeup, that was the kicker. Thanks a bunch man, saved me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `for` loop, use `while` instead:

```
std::string text;
while (std::getline(fileIn, text, '\t'))
{
  col1.push_back(text);
  std::getline(fileIn, text, '\t');
  col2.push_back(text);
  std::getline(fileIn, text);
  col3.push_back(text);
}
```

This could be a case where you want to model each line with a structure.

```
struct Record
{
  std::string col1;
  std::string col2;
  std::string col3;
}
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (std::getline(fileIn, r.col1, '\t')
{
  std::getline(fileIn, r.col2, '\t');
  std::getline(fileIn, r.col3);
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I appreciate your comment a lot. I know my code wasn't the most elegant, but I'm always looking for ways to improve.

Answer (score 1):

Rather use something like

```
std::string val1, val2; val3;

vector<string> col1;
vector<string> col2;
vector<string> col3;

while(fileIn >> val1 >> val2 >> val3) {
    col1.push_back(val1);
    col2.push_back(val2);
    col3.push_back(val3);
}
```